# : 'Incorrect syntax near ','.' checked everyline but nope

Tags: c#

I have this annoying problem ( Incorrect syntax new ','.) I have check every line and rewrote it by myself ( I didnt copy anything from the beginning)

This is my code

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int stock = new int();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @Code, Item_Stock = @Stock", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", codeadd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", stock);

        con.Open();
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //Here is the error
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("An Item with BrCode already exists. Do you with to add to the stock?", "Item Manager", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET Item_Stock = @Stock WHERE Item_Code=@Item_Code", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Stock", stockadd));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Item_Code", codeadd.Text));
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                dt.Clear();
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Products", con);
                dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: See it would have been really helpful to know if that was a compile error or a runtime SQL exception...  Always post the whole error exactly, even the parts you don't understand.

Comment: for more information commend **Where** [sql_and_or](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Comment: Why did I downvote? You tagged your question `C#`, but it is a problem in `SQL`. That's a big difference.

Comment: Its because I thought the problem is with the C# code not with the SQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the Sql statement the , should be and

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @Code and Item_Stock = @Stock", con);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
WHERE Item_Code = @Code, Item_Stock = @Stock
```

to

```
WHERE Item_Code = @Code AND Item_Stock = @Stock
```

(or `OR`, whatever - depends on whether you're trying to union or intersect)